# Sorting on several fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am searching using Elasticsearch and would like to understand how I can add sorting on several fields in Java as described here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort.html

I have only succeeded in adding a single sort builder when preparing a search.

Thanks,

Stine

---

This is how I added sorting on a single field:

```
client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(typeName)
      .setQuery(query)
      .addSort(fieldSort("activity").order(DESC).missing("_last"))
      .setSize(limit)
      .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Seems that I am not alone with that problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/elasticsearch/IiQCfNIGi00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.missing("_last")` cannot be applied to boolean fields.